# Не работает .serializeArray()

Tags: jquery, serialize

Добрый вечер.
Есть форма и js, не могу понять почему не работает .serializeArray(). В консоле выводит [] (темы поднятые здесь перечитал, поэкспериментировал, но ничего не помогло).

```
      <form class="form-horizontal" id="objectInfo">                                  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Наименование*</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required  value="Все пользователи">  
          </div>
        </div>                        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="active" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Состояние*</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="active" required  value="True">  
          </div>
        </div>                        
        <div class="col-sm-10" style="text-align: center;">
          <button type="submit" id="submitObjectButton" class="btn btn-primary objectButton">Сохранить</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){      
          // submit button
          $('#objectInfo').submit(function (e) {               
            var result = { };
            var arr = $('#objectInfo').serializeArray();
            console.log(arr);
            $.each($('#objectInfo').serializeArray(), function() {
                console.log(this.name);
                console.log(this.value);
                result[this.name] = this.value;
            });   
            e.preventDefault();  
          });
        });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину, оказалось нужно добавить name для input полей, например,

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="active" id="active" required  value="True">
```

Всем спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

serializeArray() примените не к каждому контролу отдельно, а ко всей форме

Comment: Так и делал, просто опечатка (результаты экспериментов)...

Comment: приведите пример рабочего кода, дабы показать работоспособность вашего варианта

Comment: Это и есть "рабочий код" (неработающий), убрано несколько input-ов так как их слишком много. Или выложить всю "портянку"? Могу лишь предположить, что причина в том что данная форма получается/добавляется на сайт ajax запросом... может в этом дело?!